# iOS Mobile Safari: focused input doesn't fire any click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I am not sure if this is a bug or some sort of apple-specific "feature", but it's causing me all sorts of issues.  I have reproduced the problem in [this Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/478071zK7jvbLZdqfGnk/preview).  Please open up the plunker on your iOS device in mobile safari and you should see what I'm talking about.

The issue is pretty simple.  I have a single `<input>` element and I've used jQuery to attach a `.on('click')` handler to the input.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="iosInput">
    <h4 id="result"></h4>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#iosInput').on('click', function(e){
    $('#result').text('e.offsetX = ' + e.offsetX);
});
```

I want the click handler to show me where on the `<input>` the user clicked/tapped.  I need to find the `x` coordinate for the click/tap event.  The problem is that iOS Mobile Safari only fires the click event on the first click (when the user focuses on the input and the on-screen keyboard appears).  Once the input has focus, the click event is no longer firing.

Is there some way to make the click event fire even after the `<input>` has focus?  I need to be able to calculate the relative x coordinate of any click or tap events on the input, regarless of whether the on-screen keyboard is visible or not...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

PS.  I originally discovered this issue in my AngularJS app, but it appears to happen even without angular, using only jQuery or even just pure javascript.

**Update:** As per @JackPattishallJr's suggestion, I added the FastClick library, and just as I suspected, it doesn't seem to do anything different. The Plunker has been updated.

Comment: I want to point out that you can't get the offset of a keyboard click on iOS. So if you click a key, your not going to get an offset value.

Comment: I don't need to track keyboard clicks, only when the user taps specifically on the `<input>` element.  Which is why i'm only listening for `click` events, not `keydown`/`keyup`/`keypress` events...

Comment: Are you open to using a library like FastClick? It simulates click events via touchstart/end, which (in my testing) does what you're looking for (along with just making mobile web apps just feel snappier).

Comment: I'd rather not but can if I have to.  I tried adding an additional handler for `.on('click touchstart')` but that didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. I updated the Plunker to include FastClick, but it doesn't seem to do anything different... mind taking a look? http://embed.plnkr.co/478071zK7jvbLZdqfGnk/preview

Comment: tried it on ios 6 on the simulator, it seems to work

Comment: @Huangism I'm on the iOS 7 simulator and its not working. It works on the first focus click, but then doesn't fire at all after that, until the user clicks off the input to hide the keyboard and then re-taps the input again.

Comment: @tennisgent - Not at all! I took a look and the only thing I would change is to bind FastClick to the element directly (rather than the body). Here are both examples to show the difference: http://goo.gl/21dD3j (FastClick attached to document.body - your code) and http://goo.gl/Ynnq08 (FastClick attached to input). I tested in both iOS simulator and a physical device. Here's the embedded link: http://embed.plnkr.co/a4w1aucgZAl11A181Qnr/preview

Comment: Interesting - just tested again today and it's not nearly as responsive as yesterday. I'll see if something has changed!